# AngularFire collectionGroup always throws error not a valid function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, ionic4, angularfire

I'm using Ionic 4 and have just integrated with AngularFire.  Collections and documents work well, however I cannot get the collectionGroup function to work - it always gives an error that the function does not exist.

Relevant code is :

```
this.user = this.firestore.collection('profile').doc(tok.uid);



 async StoreRecipe(recipe_name,meal) {

     var ua = await this.read_foods_meal(meal+1)
     console.log(meal);
     ua.subscribe( foods => { console.log(foods);
        foods.forEach(food =>  { this.user.collection('recipe').doc(recipe_name).collection('foods').add(food);} )
     });

 }
 
 async read_recipes() {
     
     var ua = await this.user.collectionGroup('recipe');
     return(ua);
 }
```

I have updated all modules with 'Fire' in the name to the latest version :
@angular/fire
@ionic-native/firebase-x
angularfire
firebase
firebase-admin

But the error still appears.  Also, If I try to query the recipe collection  using the .collection() function it just returns a null result  ..  even though there are documents under the 'recipe'collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `user` object is an instance of the `firebase.firestore.DocumentReference` class, and it does not have a `collectionGroup` method. Check the documetation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference).

If you want to run a query across various collections, these should have the same name, and you can use the `firebase.firestore().collectionGroup()` method. You can find how to configure it in [this link](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/06/understanding-collection-group-queries.html).

If you just want to get all the documents inside your `recipe` collection, you can make use of the `CollectionReference.get()` method ([documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data)).